# How get all the list of buttons in user control properties from the form where the user control is being used

Tags: c#, user-controls

I am using user control in c# with 
i want to create a user control with a property that have all the list of buttons of the form where the user control is used
thankx

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i tried to make a control with a property

Comment: but i don't know that how to get the list of buttons of that form

Comment: @Blachshma means, show us some code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    public IEnumerable<Button> Buttons
    {
        get
        {
            List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
            foreach (Control ctrl in ParentForm.Controls)
            {
                Button btn = ctrl as Button;
                if (btn != null)
                {
                    buttons.Add(btn);
                }
            }
            return buttons;
        }
    }
```